# How to aggregate duplicate rows with multiple columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this (however with a larger number of columns and rows):

```
    Gene      Cell1    Cell2    Cell3     
1      A          2        7        8 
2      A          5        2        9 
3      B          2        7        8
4      C          1        4        3
```

I want to sum the rows that have the same value in `Gene`, in order to get something like this:

```
    Gene      Cell1    Cell2    Cell3     
1      A          7        9       17  
2      B          2        7        8
3      C          1        4        3
```

Based on the answers to previous questions, I've tried to use `aggregate` but I could not understand how I can get the above result. This is what I've tried:

```
aggregate(df[,-1], list(df[,1]), FUN = sum)
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what's wrong with the result you've got with aggregate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
aggregate(df[,-1], list(Gene=df[,1]), FUN = sum)
#   Gene Cell1 Cell2 Cell3
# 1    A     7     9    17
# 2    B     2     7     8
# 3    C     1     4     3
```

will give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: There's an error, when we run the above: `Error in aggregate.data.frame(df[, -1], list(Gene = df[, 1]), FUN = sum) : 
  arguments must have same length`

Comment: @ManojKumar Please add the output of `str(df)` to your post.

Comment: Sure @lukeA  here it is : `Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Gene : chr  "A" "A" "B" "C"
 $ Cell1: int  2 5 2 1
 $ Cell2: int  7 2 7 4
 $ Cell3: int  8 9 8 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> `

Comment: @ManojKumar thx. You got a data table object; indexing is a bit different there. So you could e.g. do `aggregate(df[,-1], list(Gene=df[[1]]), FUN = sum)`. But if you got a data table anyway, you may want to use its strengths in aggregating data; `df[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=Gene]`.

Answer (score 4):

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarise_all(sum) %>%
  data.frame() -> newdf # so that newdf can further be used, if needed
```

Comment: the other methods work but this is more robust as well as intuitive. I like that one does not need to declare what columns to sum.